# Compartir un json data usando unicamente un $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hola miembros de StackOverFlow.

Este es mi codigo.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    var promise = $http.get("url1")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.files = []
            return $http.get('url2', {
                params: {
                    id: response.data[0].Id
                }
            })
        })
    .then(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
        $scope.files = response2.data;
        return response2.data;
    })
}])
```

mi HTML

```
div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="category">
    <a href="{{file.Url}}"><strong>{{file.Name}}</strong></a>
    <ul ng-if="(files | filter:{ParentId : file.Id}).length > 0">
        <li ng-repeat="file in files | filter: {ParentId : file.Id" ng-include="'category'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<ul class="btn-highlight plus">
    <li ng-repeat="file in files | filter: {ParentId : 0}" ng-include="'category'"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Tengo una pregunta, ParentId es solo una variable, ParentId = response.data.Id , como puedo incluir en mi $scope.files el response y el response2 al mismo tiempo y mostrar el response.data.Id en mi codigo html.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es concatenar ambas respuestas.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("url1")
      .then(function (response) {
          $scope.files = []
          $http.get('url2', {
              params: {
                  id: response.data[0].Id
              }
          }).then(function (response2) {
              // Al finalizar la segunda petición
              // si response.data es el vector entonces quedaría así:
              $scope.files = response.data.concat(response2.data);
          });
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo así?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.parentId = null;
    var promise = $http.get("url1")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.files = [];
            $scope.parentId = response.data.id;
            return $http.get('url2', {
                params: {
                    id: response.data[0].Id
                }
            })
        })
    .then(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
        $scope.files = response2.data;
        return response2.data.map;
    })
}])
```

Podés usar `$scope.parentId` para lo que necesites.